# Android application crashing (IllegalArgumentException)

Tags: java, android, illegalargumentexception

My Android application crashes suddenly. I am not able to trace the problem.

I have many custom views wherein I recycle the imageviews on detachwindow, and each instance of custom view have an Handler object.

This is my call stack; please help me find the problem.

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception IllegalArgumentException))  
    <VM does not provide monitor information>   
    Choreographer.doCallbacks(int, long) line: 594  
    Choreographer.doFrame(long, int) line: 561  
    Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run() line: 777 
    Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 725   
    Choreographer$FrameHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92   
    Looper.loop() line: 176 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5317    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 1102 
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 869 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: I doubt anyone will be able to help without some code. Just your call stack isn't likely to do much.

Comment: What is the code at Choreographer.doCallbacks(int, long) line: 594 ?

Comment: Hi guys thanks for humble comments. actually i was recycling the drawable of imageview on detachwindow. Please help me how to recycle the drawables loaded from resource. say Iamgeview.setImageResource(resource id). over the time i get OOM exception at this call . how can i clear this drawables??